# Iphone uiwebview and uitableview together possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UITableView which is long and scrollable, also I use UINAvigationController. At the bottom of the page in the footer I plan to put a next button which will help to go next page.

The problem is "sometimes" this page may need to show some messages in html, so I must use uiwebview preferebaly at the bottom of the page just above the footer, it shouldnt get effected from scrolling.

-Can I use uitableview and uiwebview on same page? the page is already in control of a uitableview controller, so how will i control or put delegates of a uiwebview?

-Can I make this uiwebview invisible and not allocate space when there are no messages to be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

I believe the Stocks app for the iPhone utilizes multiple views with their own controllers. I think a better solution would be is to have a `UIPageControl` and create a `UITableViewController` when the `UIPageControl`'s value changed.

If you still want to create `UINavigationController`, just set its `rootViewController` to a `UITableViewController` and set its `toolbarHidden` property to `NO`, the `toolbar` has the behavior you want, it stays fixed on the bottom of the screen, if that's what you meant. Then add the navigational buttons.

As for `UIWebView's`, just dynamically create it once you get an error and set its `hidden` property to `YES`. You wouldn't want to be destroying and recreating `UIWebView`s every time you get an error as that can be very expensive. Just create once and hide it.

Comment: thanks, The UIWebView is either there whole time or not for each page, if any messages for the page it should stay on page during scrolling the tableview and it should be gone next time if there is no messages on next page, so what do you think?